# Entity Framework - making a large edmx table more manageable by splitting?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I think this is a question of the best technique or best way to skin a cat!

Imagine a menu with items (menu choices) on it.  I have a table called MenuItem, which for example "Spaghetti Bolognese", it has lots of other information associated with it aside from just a better description and picture.
Eg.

- Basic Information (Name, Description, Picture, etc)
- Nutritional Information (approx 15 columns)
- Allergy Information (approx 16 columns)
- Dietary Information (another 7 columns)  (religious etc)

As it is at the moment I have it all in the **one** table in SQL server, which is logical database design to me as it doesn't repeat, despite it making the field list for the table longer than I would like.  I'd already been feeling a bit bad about just continually extending the database table.  But now we also want to add 'Recipe' information, approx another 7 columns.

I'm using Entity Framework 4.latest, and feel there is probably functionality to help me split this off within the EDMX?  (Is that what ComplexTypes are?)  Or do I just need to do this in the ViewModel class I call?

I think what I'm after using in my code to segregate things better is something like

- MenuItem.Recipe.Ingredients
- MenuItem.Nutrition.Fat
- etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complex types can help you but be aware that complex types cannot contain navigation properties, cannot be null and are always loaded with the entity. Other possibility is to use [table splitting](http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/ef-table-splitting-ndash-the-opposite-of-entity-splitting/) - this will allow you to map multiple one-to-one related entities to the same table. The main features of table splitting are:

- Entities can share only primary key properties
- There is one main entity and others are considered as relations (navigation properties)
- Related entities must exists - they are not optional so when you insert new main entity you must insert these related entities as well even if they are empty
- Related entities must be loaded with eager, lazy or explicit loading

Comment: I originally come from a database background rather than programming.  And as such I can't bring myself to break database design to suit programming the EDMX.  I was really hoping there is a neater way of handling this problem.

Comment: This will not break your database design - you will still have your one big database table but your object model will be more granular.

Comment: I now see what you mean.  Thanks Ladislav.        
Also found another similar example in "Entity Framework 4.0 Recipes: A Problem-Solution Approach" - Recipe 2-7. Splitting a Table Across Multiple Entities.